# Chart horizontal axis label interval

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've got a graph with dates on the horizontal axis. I've used both the Auto and a hard-coded number on the label interval field. Both have worked fine.

However, when the report is used as a subreport in the Main report, the intervals get rendered differently. For example, when calling the chart report directly, I get about 10 data labels, however when its called as a subreport, I get over 20 label points, and the years are cut off

For example, it looks the below
26/08/......22/09.....

Any ideas?